# Node.js Paypal sdk: visa card is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am attempting to process credit cards with PayPal in node.js
With master card, the below code is working with sandbox account with `201` status code.
But, not working with 'visa', 'amex'.
With 'visa', 'amex' card, I am getting `500` status code, and I cannot find error details.
Who has seen this case ?

```
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

paypal.configure({
    'mode': 'sandbox',
    'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
    'client_secret': 'CLIENT_SECRET_KEY'
});

var payment = {
    "intent": "authorize",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "credit_card",
        "funding_instruments": [{
            "credit_card": {
                "type": "visa",//visa//mastercard//amex
                "expire_month": 1,
                "expire_year": 2022,
                "cvv2": "VISA_CCV2",
                "number": "VISA_NUMBER"
            }
        }]
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/err"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "media dvd",
                "sku": "001",
                "price": "1.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "total": 1.00,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "description": " a book on mean stack "
    }]
}

paypal.payment.create(payment, { timeout: 10000 }, function (err, payment) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, payment);


    }
    else {
        console.log(payment);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are passing a credit card number to PayPal in text form? Read the documentation on developer.paypal.com This integration is not enabled for use in live. You should not integrate this. It is not supported and will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/

> Important: The use of the PayPal REST /payments APIs to accept credit card payments is restricted. Instead, you can accept credit card payments with Braintree Direct.

(Braintree direct would be a full gateway account, which requires account approval and is only available for businesses [in certain countries.](https://www.braintreepayments.com/country-selection))

Since you were attempting to integrate something old, with an old SDK, and that cannot be used in the live environment -- here is the best PayPal alternative:

- Use the new, supported v2 [Checkout-NodeJS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK)
- Use the PayPal Checkout front-end, with its black Debit/Credit Card button: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Answer (score 1):

The payment direct is restricted from credit card to paypal.
So, you can implement payment integration using **Braintree Direct**.

```
const braintree = require("braintree");

const gateway = new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
   environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox, // Sandbox or Production
   merchantId: "Your_merchatn_id",
   publicKey: "Your_public key",
   privateKey: "Your_private_key"
});
```

You can authonticate using **merchantId, publicKey, privateKey**.

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
        amount: `10`,
        paymentMethodNonce: "fake-valid-nonce",
        options: {
          submitForSettlement: true,
          storeInVaultOnSuccess: true
        }
      }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      
        if (result.success) {
          console.log('Transaction ID: ' + result.transaction.id);
          console.log('Customer ID: ' + result.transaction.customer.id);
            var customer_id = result.transaction.customer.id;
            let creditCardParams = {
                customer_id,
                number: `4111111111111111`,
                expirationDate: `04/2022`,
                cvv: `133`
              };
              
              gateway.creditCard.create(creditCardParams, (err, response) => {
                  if(err) {
                      console.log(err.message);
                  } else {
                      console.log(response);
                  }
              });
         } else {
             console.error(result);
         }
     });
```